# Cortar looping de relacionamento bidirecional

Tags: java, jpa, spring, rest

Estou com um projeto Spring, usando JPA e liquibase, tenho um relacionamento bidirecional entre duas entidades, gostaria de saber se alguém tem uma solução para o problema de referenciação infinita entre as duas? Exemplificando tenho uma Question que tem muitas answers, uma answer tem essa question que tem essa answer e assim vai tendendo ao infinito, não posso perder a bidirecionalidade entao a annotation `@IgnoreJson` não seria interessante. Segue minhas entidades.

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question extends BasicForum{

private String title;
private Integer views;

@OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "question")
private List<Answer> answerList;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answer")
public class Answer extends BasicForum {

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Question question;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, deixei a pergunta meio esquecida, mas o que eu fiz para resolver isso foi:

Basicamente eu removi a lista de `Answer` de dentro de `Question`, e criei um método no `Controller` que me retorna as `Answers` a partir da `Question`.

*Controller:*

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/question/{id}")
public List<Answer> getAnswersByQuestion(@PathVariable("id") final String id) {
        return repository.findByQuestionIdAndDeadIsFalse(id);
}
```

---

*Repository:*

```
@Repository
public interface AnswerRepository extends SuperRepository<Answer> {
    List<Answer> findByQuestionIdAndDeadIsFalse(String questionId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode dar um Lazy na Question da entidade Answer, assim ele não vai buscar a question.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answer")
public class Answer extends BasicForum {

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
private Question question;
```